# SSL Certificate at a specific URL on Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

Is there possible to configurate the SSL Certificate Key File (Two Way) for a specific URL inside the domain?

Yes, using `mod_rewrite`. But I really need to keep the domain and the URL that was requested.

Current `domain.com.conf` configuration:

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:443>
    ServerAdmin name@domain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key

    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/ca.cer

    <location />
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        SSLRequire (%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN} eq "clientcn")
    </location>

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
    <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /usr/local/apache2/conf/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache2/conf/logs/ssl_access.log combined

    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*"\
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The certificate is valid for all url's on the domain

Comment: Thats the question. Is possible disable it for a set URL and hability for another set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No [this is not possible](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20803/132503).

The SSL handshake happens at the server level before any route/endpoint dispatching takes place. The full URL in the HTTP header is not even considered until after a successful TLS negotiation.

For example, use curl on this URL to see that it first connects to the host, and then if and only if a trusted connection is formed does it pass the URI stem.

```
curl -vI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718090/ssl-certificate-at-a-specific-url-on-apache
```

> ```
> *   Trying 151.101.193.69...
> * Connected to stackoverflow.com (151.101.193.69) port 443 (#0)
> * found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
> * found 714 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
> * ALPN, offering http/1.1
> * SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> *      server certificate verification OK
> *      server certificate status verification SKIPPED
> *      common name: *.stackexchange.com (matched)
> *      server certificate expiration date OK
> *      server certificate activation date OK
> *      certificate public key: RSA
> *      certificate version: #3
> *      subject: C=US,ST=NY,L=New York,O=Stack Exchange\, Inc.,CN=*.stackexchange.com
> *      start date: Sat, 21 May 2016 00:00:00 GMT
> *      expire date: Wed, 14 Aug 2019 12:00:00 GMT
> *      issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
> *      compression: NULL
> * ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> > HEAD /questions/42718090/ssl-certificate-at-a-specific-url-on-apache HTTP/1.1
> > Host: stackoverflow.com
> > User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> > Accept: */*
> ```